# Updating logged in user: express node js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have been working on this for too many hours to no avail. I just simply want to update user data, but it seems to be something I am not understanding. in app.post(..); I feel like I was handling the problem correctly, But I am getting "undefined is not a function" where "var activity = new activity({title: req.body["activities.title"]});". I am lost..please help!

```
var passport = require('passport');
var Account = require('./models/user');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var connect = require('connect');
var activity = require('mongoose').model('activity').schema;
module.exports = function (app, models) {



  app.get('/home', function (req, res) {
      if (req.user){ console.log('userin');
    }
      res.render('home', { user : req.user });

  });


  app.get('/register', function(req, res) {
      res.render('register', { });
  });

  app.post('/register', function(req, res) {
      Account.register(new Account({ username : req.body.username }), req.body.password, function(err, account) {
          if (err) {
            return res.render("register", {info: "Sorry. That username already exists. Try again."});
          }

          passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
            res.redirect('/');
          });
      });
  });



 app.get('/schedule', function(req, res) {
    res.render('schedule', { user : req.user });

 });


app.post('/schedule', function(req, res){
  var activity = new activity({title: req.body["activities.title"]});
  activity.user = req.user;
  activity.save(function(err){
    if(!err){
      res.redirect('/schedule');

    }
    else{
      res.redirect('/');
    }
   });
});

  app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
      res.render('login', { user : req.user });
  });





app.get('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/schedule');
  });

app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/schedule',
                                   failureRedirect: '/login' })



  );

// in case of depreciation
/*app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
      res.redirect('/');
  });*/

  app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
      req.logout();
      res.redirect('/');
  });

  app.get('/ping', function(req, res){
      res.send("pong!", 200);
  });

};
```

Below is my models file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;



var location = new Schema({
  state: String,
  city: String,
  location: String

});

var user = new Schema({
    activities: [activities]

},

{collection:'user'});

var activities = new Schema ({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    location: [location],
    time: String,
    date: String,
    invite:[user],
    notes: [notes]


});



var notes = new Schema({
    notes: String

});


user.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

//export schema model .........> name   schemas
module.exports = mongoose.model('user', user);
var activity = mongoose.model('activity', activities);
```

my app file looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var fortune = require('./lib/fortune.js');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var session = require('express-session');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Account = require('./models/user');
var connect = require('connect');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

// set up handlebars
var handlebars = require('express3-handlebars')
       .create({ defaultLayout: 'main', helpers: {
        section: function(name, opions){
            if(!this._sections) this._sections = {};
            this._sections[name] = options.fn(this);
            return null
        }
       }
   });

app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());





app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
 console.log('Express started on http://localhost:' + app.get('port') + ';press Ctrl-C to terminate.');
});


app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.showTests = app.get('env') !== 'production' && 
          req.query.test === '1';
    next();
});

app.use(function(req, res, next){
 if(!res.locals.partials) res.locals.partials = {};
 res.locals.partials.weather = getWeatherData();
 next();
});



app.get('/about', function(req, res) {
    res.render('about', {
     fortune: fortune.getFortune(),
     pageTestScript: '/qa/tests-about.js'} );
});
app.get('/schedule', function(req, res){
    res. render('schedule', {csrf: 'CSRF token goes here'});
});

app.post('/process', function(req, res){
    console.log('Form (from querysting):' + req.queryform);
    console.log('CSRF token (from hidden form field): ' + req.body._csrf);
    console.log('Name (from visible form field): ' + req.body.name);
    console.log('Email (from visible form field): ' + req.body.email);
    res.redirect(303, '/thank-you');
});

app.get('/tours/rivercity', function(req, res){
        res.render('tours/rivercity');
});

app.get('/tours/oregonhill', function(req,res){
        res.render('tours/oregonhill');
});

app.get('/tours/request-group-rate', function(req, res){
    res.render('tours/request-group-rate');
});

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.render('home');

});
app.get('/home', function(req,res){
    res.render('home');

});
app.get('/about', function(req, res){
    res.render('about', {fortune: fortune.getFortune()} );
});




// routes
require('./routes')(app);

//custom 404 page 
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.status(404);
    res.send('404 - Not Found');
});


// 500 error handler (middleware)
app.use(function(err, req, ers, next){
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500);
    res.render('500');
});

//custom 404 page
app.use(function(req, res){
        res.type('text/plain');
        res.status(404);
        res.send('404 - Not Found');
});

//custom 500 page
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.status(500);
    res.send('500 - Server Error');
});




var User = require('./models/user');
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/stoosh');
```

im using the handlebars templating engine as seen below

```
<form role='form' action="/schedule" method="POST" >
title:<br>
<input type="text" name="activities[title]">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring "activity" as a variable twice

```
var activity = require('mongoose').model('activity').schema;
// blah, blah, blah
app.post('/schedule', function(req, res){
   var activity = new activity({title: req.body["activities.title"]});
```

The "new" command is being applied to the newly declared activity variable instead of the previously declared one.  Instead try,

```
app.post('/schedule', function(req, res){
    var newActivity = new activity({title: req.body["activities.title"]});
```

Comment: ahh that makes sense, but I am getting the same error. Is there something else that could be causing the issue?

Comment: Is require('mongoose').model('activity').schema actually a function?  I am not familiar with Mongoose but (just from the name) it doesn't sound like a method.

Comment: What that does is calls the activities collection into the file. The model is defined from the models file and evoked in that one...I've added the files for my models and app to help get a better scope of what I may be doing wrong.